# Share point calculated columns

Tags: share

I am trying to generate column called `status_mode` which should have the outputs `DONE`, `PENDING`, or `DELAYED`. But I am comparing **two** columns one is `DATE REQUESTED` and other is `FAD_CODE`. Below is my formulae.

```
=IF(FAD_CODE>1,"DONE","PENDING"),if(DATE REQUESTED+3,"DELAYED","PENDING")
```

Conditions i am applying.

- If FAD_CODE field is blank it should show Pending
- If FAD_CODE got value it should show DONE
- If FAD_CODE field is blank for three days it should show DELAYED

please help.

Comment: it is quite tough to create calculated formulas in Sharepoint Try to use excel to get what you want (the engine is pretty much the same) https://www.cnblogs.com/batter152/p/4503696.html

Comment: What is the type of FAD_CODE field? Date or number or something else?

Comment: Hi Ganesh, the FAD_CODE field type is text

Answer (score 3):

Note: `[Today]` isn't typically accepted in Calculated Columns (there are workarounds) but you can alternatively use the function `Today()` in its place! The original command below the divide would therefore be this:

```
=if(NOT([FAD_CODE]=""),"DONE",if(([DATE_REQUESTED]+3)>=Today(),"DELAYED","PENDING"))
```

---

Try something like this:

```
=if(NOT([FAD_CODE]=""),"DONE",if(([DATE_REQUESTED]+3)>=[Today],"DELAYED","PENDING"))
```

It first checks if `FAD_CODE` **is not** blank. If FAD_CODE is not blank, outputs `DONE`. If it is blank, it checks to see if the `DATE_REQUESTED + 3` is greater than today. If it is, the output is `DELAYED`, Otherwise it's `PENDING`.

This may not be perfect, so try it out, do some fiddling, and let me know what happens if it doesn't work properly.

Comment: Hi Glasier, thanks for reply. The formulae didn't work. Below is the error message.   Calculated columns cannot contain volatile functions like Today and Me.

Comment: @Raj Apologies, forgot about that restriction. Try replacing `[Today]` with `Today()` and see if that works. I believe that the variable `[Today]` doesn't work because its a variable that's volatile and doesn't update when its supposed to in lists. `Today()` is a function, which should(?) update. I'll reflect this in my answer.

Comment: Hi Glasier, thank you it worked perfectly, but i did little change. Please see below.  =if(NOT([FAD]=""),"DONE",if(([DATE]+3)>=Today(),"PENDING","DELAYED"))

Comment: Sorry @Raj I just used the variables you had in your original question. **Please note** though, I don't know if the `Today()` will update every day. If it doesn't you'll need to either set some sort of workflow system to update the item every day or just edit *any* column to refresh the values. Also, if you could mark my answer as "Approved" (the checkmark to the left) that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think this one will resolve your problem :

```
=IF( [FAD_CODE]="", "PENDING", 
   IF( ([DATE_REQUESTED]+3)>=[Today], "DELAYED", 
     IF([FAD_CODE]>1, "DONE" ) ) )
```

Comment: Hi Sayyed, it didn't work. Please is below error message.Calculated columns cannot contain volatile functions like Today and Me

Comment: Actually problem is in Date.. Try to search how to implement Date in Calculated Columns

Answer (score 0):

**After some search i got this one.
Try this one it may be helpful for you ..**
You cannot directly specify today and me in calculated column to set the values. You will have to create columns named Today and Me and then use it in your calculated column.

Once you are done with the formula for the calculated column, you need to delete the 2 columns created for this. I think this will make your things work.

Comment: You can not use `[Today]` in calculated columns without your stated method, but you *can* use `Today()`. This is a build in function that gets the current date, rather than a dynamic variable. You can see in the comments of my post that Raj was able to get the formula to work with the function `=if(NOT([FAD]=""),"DONE",if(([DATE]+3)>=Today(),"PENDING","DELAYED")) `

Comment: Thanx for information